# React - Link redirect to item but not refresh the component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

When I click StageItem 'Details', URL is being changed but Stage component not refresh the data. I was trying to use Switch and withRouter, without success, because I completely don't know how to use these in my case. Thanks in advance for answers. My code:

App

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="App">
            <Header/>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <Route path='/' component={InputContainer}/>
                    <Route path='/' component={() => <StagesList todos={this.props.todos}/>} />
                    <Route path='/:stage_id' render={(props) => <Stage {...props} todos={this.props.todos}/>} />
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        todos: state.todos
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {};

export const AppContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

StageItem

```
export const StageItem = ({ todo, id, handleRemoveTodo}) => {

    return(
        <li className="stage_item" key={id}><span onClick={() => handleRemoveTodo(id)}><FontAwesomeIcon className="fa" icon="trash" />&nbsp;{todo.tour} - {todo.duration.hours}:{String(todo.duration.minutes).padStart(2,"0")}:{String(todo.duration.seconds).padStart(2,"0")} - {todo.distance} km - {todo.avgSpeed} km/h - {todo.maxSpeed} km/h</span><Link to={'/'+todo.id}>Details</Link></li>
    )

};
```

StagesList

```
export class StagesListC extends React.Component{

    render(){

        return(
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <SectionTitle title="Stage list"/>
                {this.props.todos.length>0 ?
                <ul className="todo-list">
                    {this.props.todos.map((todo) => <StageItem
                        key={todo.id}
                        id = {todo.id}
                        todo={todo}
                        handleRemoveTodo = {this.props.handleRemoveTodo}
                    />)}
                </ul>
                :
                <div>You have no stages</div>}
            </div>
        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
    handleRemoveTodo
}, dispatch)

const mapDispatchToProps = { handleRemoveTodo };

export const StagesList = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(StagesListC);
```

Full project: [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/olg4m8ftqbbvidn/App%20new%205.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Anybody help???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `exact` to your `/` routes if you don't want to see the `InputContainer` and `StagesList` while you are at `:stage_id` route.

```
<div className="row">
    <Route path='/' exact component={InputContainer}/>
    <Route path='/' exact component={() => <StagesList todos={this.props.todos}/>} />
    <Route path='/:stage_id' render={(props) => <Stage {...props} todos={this.props.todos}/>} />
</div>
```

There is also a bug in your `Stage` component.

`todo.id` is an integer, but `stage_id` is a string. To fix it you can convert both to string, e.g.

```
let stage = todos.filter((todo) => String(todo.id) === String(id));
```

UPD:

If you want to see `StageList` and `Stage` components at all time, you need to fix the `Stage` component. The `Stage` component updates its `state.stage` value only once, when `componentDidMount` is fired. All subsequent updates do not update `stage.stage` value. You can implement `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method and update `stage.stage` value whenever props are changed. Alternatively, you don't use the `state.stage` and compute `stage` value on the fly in `render` method, like so:

```
class Stage extends React.Component {

    getStage = () => {
        const todos = this.props.todos || [];
        let id = this.props.match.params.stage_id;
        return todos.filter((todo) => String(todo.id) === String(id))[0];
    }

    render() {

        const stage = this.getStage();

        if (!stage) return null;

        return <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <SectionTitle title="Single stage"/>
            <div>Id: {stage.id}</div>
            <div>Distance: {stage.distance}</div>
            <div>Duration: {stage.duration.hours}:{String(stage.duration.minutes).padStart(2, "0")}:{String(stage.duration.seconds).padStart(2, "0")}</div>
            <div>Average speed: {stage.avgSpeed} km/h</div>
            <div>Max speed: {stage.maxSpeed} km/h</div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I discovered this '===' bug earlier. With 'exact' works as expected. But the most important question for me was - it is possible to keep 'StagesList' and show 'Stage' and switch 'Stage' by clicking on 'StagesList'?

Comment: @scartout Yes, it is possible. The problem is that you're updating `Stage` component only once when `componentDidMount` is fired. The easiest solution  would be to move the filtering logic into `render` method. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for your response.